# Difference between "farther on" and "ahead" in these examples

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between "farther on", "ahead" and "farther ahead" in these examples related to physical locations? For example; does one of them denote a greater distance or a more literary/old-fashioned style than another? Doing some Google searches I learned that "ahead" is the most popular.

> Tim was walking by the river when, 20 yards **ahead/farther on/farther ahead,** he
>   saw a deer galloping past.
>
> **Ahead/Farther ahead/Farther on** in the misty distance there gleamed a fire.

Comment: Though there *might* be a slight connotation of greater distance with `farther on` and `farther ahead`, for all practical purposes all three are used interchangeably.

Comment: Furthermore, [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=farther+ahead%2Cfurther+ahead&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) might interest you.

Comment: Yes, @J.R. "further ahead" can be added too in the list. Probably "further" is more common than "farther" in the Ngram because it is used for non-literal distances too.

Answer (score 1):

**further** and **farther** are comparatives, and **ahead** and **on** are deictic.

If something is further or farther ahead|on, it is further|farther ahead of a specified reference point which is itself **ahead** of another reference point:

> The bank is two blocks ahead. The library is several blocks further|farther ahead|on.

or it is farther|further ahead of a reference point which is  **ahead** of where it itself used to be:

> We have gone ten miles into the jungle. The dig site lies two miles further|farther ahead|on.

*If you have not set out on your twelve-mile journey to the dig site yet but are just about to set out*, you would not say:

> The dig site lies further|farther ahead|on.

because the comparative would be in comparison to nothing, which doesn't fly.

But you could say:

> The dig site lies ahead.